# In Django, how do I avoid/skip/undo a pre-save event?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-extensions

I am using [django_extensions TimeStampedModel](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/field_extensions.html), which provides a `modified` field that sets itself via a `pre_save` event.  Which is great, except I am converting an old schema and want to preserve the original `modified` datestamp.  How can I monkeypatch, avoid, cancel, or replace the pre_save'd modified with another value?

Comment: If it is a pre_save signal you have created, can you not - maybe passing a kwarg to not override the timestamp? Alternatively, if it is a 3rd party apps' signal, just dont all it, create your own with custom code - disclaimer - this is just a thought. I may be way off in understanding what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just did an end-around:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("update %s set modified='%s' where id=%s" % (
    my_model._meta.db_table, desired_modified_date, my_model.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Not in the sense you're asking.

What you can is create a fake field and populate it on `clean()`.

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):

    def clean(self):
        self._modified = self.modified

...

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def receiver_(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.modified = self._modified
```

So you're backing up the field value and putting it back later. **notes**: ensure your application is loaded *later*.

Comment: "Ensure your application is loaded later" than what?

Comment: I tried doing this and it runs before the other `pre_save`... how can I affect the order?

Comment: You cannot affect the order. think as it is executed code. You must somehow ensure the application's code is run later *than the timestamps extension*, so the code calling `connect` (signal) for your application is called AFTER the code calling `connect` in the timestamps extension.